# I got effected by GANDCRAB ransomeware and all my files & documents got encrypted and .WRCOR file extension got added orginal file name

Tags: attacks

All my files & documents got encrypted and appended with file extension .wrcor. I was accessing a file from Tor browser. Suddenly I saw my files got converted and encrypted.

Al the original file names extension were added with .wrcor extension.
Ex. myfile.pdf file became myfile.pdf.wrcor
In all the folder where the file got conveted , a text file "WRCOR-DECRYPT.txt" is seen.

### The files contains this text

---= GANDCRAB V5.0 =---

Attention!

All your files, documents, photos, databases and other important files are encrypted and have the extension: .WRCOR

The only method of recovering files is to purchase an unique private key. Only we can give you this key and only we can recover your files.

The server with your key is in a closed network TOR. You can get there by the following ways:

---

| 0. Download Tor browser - https://www.torproject.org/

| 1. Install Tor browser 
| 2. Open Tor Browser 
| 3. Open link in TOR browser:   http://gandcrabmfe6mnef.onion/8e285315f6359a77
| 4. Follow the instructions on this page

---

On our page you will see instructions on payment and get the opportunity to decrypt 1 file for free.

ATTENTION!

IN ORDER TO PREVENT DATA DAMAGE:

- DO NOT MODIFY ENCRYPTED FILES
- DO NOT CHANGE DATA BELOW

---BEGIN GANDCRAB KEY---
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
---END GANDCRAB KEY---

---BEGIN PC DATA---
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
---END PC DATA---

---

How to recover my files. Any help

Comment: a good related question: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/i-got-infected-by-ransomware-and-it-tells-me-to-download-tor-whats-going-on

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://www.nomoreransom.org, maybe there's no way to pay anything.
BDGandCrabDecryptTool Decryptor is designed to decrypt files encrypted by GandCrab (includes v5 Syrian victims) Ransom.