# HELP ME please i don't know what to do

Tags: windows

HELP ME
I got effected by GANDCRAB ransomeware and all my files & documents got encrypted and .SBEPM file extension got added orginal file name

Comment: potential duplicate: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/i-got-infected-by-ransomware-and-it-tells-me-to-download-tor-whats-going-on

Answer (score 1):

You can decrypt your files at no cost:

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/free-decrypter-available-for-gandcrab-ransomware-victims/

More information:

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/fbi-releases-master-decryption-keys-for-gandcrab-ransomware/

Comment: these are good and promising links... but link-only answers unfortunately tend to get useless because of 404. - it would be much appreciated if you can add some (at least essential) details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Malware issue. 
If you were using the TOR network while infected...not sure how helpful this Stack can be....I'm not very experienced here either.
Id research the type of Malware....here's a good starting place: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/gandcrab-ransomware-distributed-by-exploit-kits-appends-gdcb-extension/
Good Luck and Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Erase data and restore from a backup (or snapshot) if you can. This problem is more of a professional's job than fixing it on your own... maybe you should seek the advice of a consultant?